# How to execute a global feature file first every time when Karate suite is executed and store the outcome in variables to be used further?

Tags: karate

I have multiple feature files to be executed as suite. Requirement is to execute a feature file (Let's call it a.feature) very first time before the suite gets executed and store the outcome of this feature file globally to be used further in other feature files.

Let's say I am storing value of variables x and y in a.feature.
I want to use the value of x and y in:
b.feature
c.feature
.
.
.
and so on...

Please help me on this how can I achieve this functionality using Karate Framework?

Comment: this is precisely what `karate.callSingle()` is designed for. please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks